# How do I measure impedance of my guitar pickups?

Tags: analog, impedance, measurement, multimeter

How would I measure impedance of my guitar pickups with a multimeter? Is it similar to measuring resistance?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://www.syscompdesign.com/AppNotes/guitar-pickups.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the pickups have both a reactive and resistive component, it's not just as simple as measuring resistance alone. The (assuming standard coil) pickups are inductive, will have some resistance and some stray capacitance also.

The impedance is calculated using both components, using

$$Z = \sqrt{R^2 + X^2}$$

The resistive part is easy, just measure with a multimeter on ohms. For the reactive part you need an LC meter (which your multimeter may have, but most only have the C testing capability).

Depending on the LC meter, it may do all measurements for you and display reactive, resistive and total impedance, or it may just display reactive. You will be interested in the results over the entire frequency range (for a guitar pickup say 100Hz to 5kHz).

Or you can use a scope and known impedance/signal to drive the coil with and do the necessary calculations.

IIRC, wound guitar pickups are usually in the 5k - 100k range at audio frequencies, but my memory is fuzzy so this may be a bit out.

Comment: Lowest note on a guitar is about 78Hz; bass guitar 39Hz. I don't know what '5k-100k' is supposed to mean, but the last pickup I measured (Fender) was about 3mH.

Comment: I'd say oli meant 5-100 kOhms

Answer (score 0):

In order to measure the impedance you need to get a hold of a device called an LCR meter. The device is capable of measuring inductance (L), capacitance (C) and resistance (R). Note that the guitar pickup can be represented by a network of lumped elements. A model which is used a lot is a coil with resistor is series and a capacitor is parallel to both of them. Ideally the pickup is an inductor, however the wire is not ideal and has some resistance which explains the R is series and because of the voltage drop across the coil (together with the obvious geometry) you will get parasitic capacitance in parallel with the L+R.

The LCR meter can be defined to measure the "complex" network and represent an accurate impedance which is comprised from the square root of the impedance of each element in the network raised in the power of 2.

Things get more complicated though, because the impedance of reactive elements (L & C) is freq. dependent, for different frequencies you will get different impedaneces! Another dependency is on voltage! Different test voltages will affect the said values (L & C thus affecting Xc & Xl) of the pickup and the behavior is of course non-linear.

Usually one would try to stick to a standard freq. and voltage in order to present uniform data. With guitar pickups it is 1Vppk at 1KHz. Of course this is not always the case because there is no real standard but many people will use those figures to take the reading.